# Is there a way to SELECT the TOP N rows from a table and delete them afterwards?

Tags: sql, teradata

I'd like to achieve the following within Teradata.

Given a table, I'd like to

- get the TOP N rows from a table, e.g., `SELECT TOP 100 * FROM table ORDER BY idx`
- delete those rows afterwards, e.g. `DELETE FROM table WHERE idx IN (SELECT TOP 100 idx FROM table ORDER BY idx)`

The second query doesn'T even work (TOP not allowed in subquery).

Would there be a straight forward way to achieve this behaviour? Ideally even in one rush, but I could also use locks.

I also looked into Queue tables, but they only allow `TOP 1`, so obviously designed to pop exactly one element at a time.

Comment: I don't know teradata, do you have temporary tables? Insert the IDs into a temp table, then select from the temp table join to table to return rows, then same to delete.

Comment: Is delete top permitted?

Comment: Does it not allow top 100 even when there is an order by clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Top N option is not supported in subquery

It's just not allowed in a *subquery*, but you can wrap it in a *Derived Table*:

```
DELETE FROM table 
WHERE idx IN 
 ( SELECT *
   FROM
    ( SELECT TOP 100 idx FROM table ORDER BY idx
    ) AS dt
 )
```

A subquery might be *Correlated*, but not a Derived Table :-)

But, why do you actually need this?
Hopefully not in a loop to get smaller transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temp table. Example:

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE tmp_top_100_idx AS
(SELECT TOP 100 * FROM table ORDER BY idx)
WITH DATA
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS

DELETE FROM table 
WHERE idx IN (SELECT idx FROM tmp_top_100_idx)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would probably work, but @dnoeth s answer is a bit more lightweight.

Comment: @ThorstenKranz agreed. Thanks.